# Get and redirect to url from uri

Tags: php, redirect

I want to redirect after log in to url which is in the uri. My code now is:

```
if ( $count == 1 && $row['userPass']==$password && $row['online']=="N") {
    $_SESSION['user'] = $row['userID'];
    mysql_query("UPDATE users SET online='Y' WHERE userID=".$_SESSION['user']);
    if (isset($_GET['url'])) {
        $back==$_GET['url'];
        header("Location: ".$back);
        exit;
    } else {
        header("Location: /subdom/demo/");
        exit;
    }
}
```

But it redirects to the main page, not the page from uri. URL is like **localhost/subdom/demo/login.php?url=/subdom/demo/mixy.php**. Why is it not working?

Comment: Mysql library is deprecated see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysql.php), and your code is vulnerable to SQL injection, Use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead

Comment: Also, it is bad practice to allow "open redirects", i.e. redirect to an URL that is specified in the URL. You should at least validate that the URL you are redirecting to is a relative URL (i.e. part of your homepage)

Comment: @giraff how can I do it? it is not working, so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you see your syntax error?

```
header("Location: $_GET['url]");
```

Change to this

```
header("Location: ". $_GET['url']);
```

Comment: Did you output something (even if only 1 whitespace) before sending the header? There is the PHP function `headers_sent()` to check this. If you can't avoid this, you need to redirect via Javascript instead.

Comment: I think i didn't output anything before it, but I'll check it at home

Answer (score 0):

try this here

```
   if (!empty($_GET['url'])) {
            header("Location: " . $_GET['url']);
            exit;
        } else {
            header("Location: /subdom/demo/");
            exit;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why not isset? Isn't it the same?

Comment: isset checks whether the variable exists.
already the empty one verifies if it is empty ... Did it work for you? if it worked, select as the best answer...